# Preventing user to access a view in a NSView hierarchy

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

Maybe this is my strange understanding of the `NSView` hierarchy, but the question is:

I have a window with a `SplitViewController` which has the classic two child views.

When the user clic a button on the toolbar I add a 'work in progress' view as follows:

```
    NSView* workingView;

    // creating the view
    ...

    [self.view addSubView:workingView];
```

where `self` is the `SplitViewController` object. My understanding (also from iOS programming) is that the split view controller has three views: left and right views and the `workingView` onto them(?)

The problem is that, even if `workingView` is covering the entire window, the two views are still accessible. In iOS developing we can set the `userInteraction` to `NO` so only the desired view is active. What about OSX?

Can I disable interaction with the split view controller views and let only the `workingView` be active?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I followed @Wain hint and I created a new ViewController that contains my work in progress view.

I presented it using the `presentViewController:animator` technique. In this way I can hav more control about the positioning of the view.

In the custom animator I simply colored the view to see what is happening. Really the way the animator adds the new view controller seems nearly the same as adding a classic view onto the split view (like did before). In fact the result is the same: even if my working view covers two buttons belonging to the left side of the split view, they are clickable!

```
    -(void)animatePresentationOfViewController:(NSViewController *)viewController fromViewController:(NSViewController *)fromViewController      {
        NSViewController* bottomVC = fromViewController;
        NSViewController* topVC = viewController;

        topVC.view.wantsLayer = YES;
        topVC.view.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = NSViewLayerContentsRedrawOnSetNeedsDisplay;
        topVC.view.alphaValue = 0.0f;

        [bottomVC.view addSubview:topVC.view];
        topVC.view.layer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor blueColor] CGColor];
        topVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);
        [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext* context){
            context.duration = 1.0f;
            topVC.view.animator.alphaValue = 1.0f;
        } completionHandler:nil];
    }
```

I know something is missing or wrong... May you help me in understanding what is going on here?

Comment: You should really use a new view controller that you present (on both platforms)...

Comment: Yes... I was thinking that, but I would like that the SplitView content remains visible in the background. The workingWindow display a semi-transparent background (as big as the window) and a small centered view. So you can always see the background... I know is only a "visual" need!

Comment: Rather than doing this in the split view controller, can't you do this in the window that holds the split view?  It's then just a question of keeping the "work in progress" view in front of the split view.  This could be done in the window controller.

Comment: In the Window Controller windowDidLoad method I added a simple view covering some split view's buttons... unfortunately if you click them, they respond!

Comment: I don't think that requirement was ever mentioned by you.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new view controller to manage your new view and then present it as a form sheet. The display style is slightly different on each platform but this is the correct approach.

An alternative is the screenshot the split view and pass the image to the new controller which is presented full size. It then applies an overlay and adds its own content view in front of the background image.

Comment: Thanks... but the window is resizable. Affine transformations (scale) are quite visible when window grows :)

Comment: Then the form sheet option is best. Or add the new view as a subview of the split view supervise.

Comment: I edited my question following your first hint of creating a new view controller (solution I find elegant :) )